# Vlookup for the first chars (or any other formula)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In first sheet, name column write (Shiv), and second sheet column write only ( Shi ), how can `vlookup` or any other formula help me match the values from first sheet to the second?

First sheets data.

```
Name    Salary
Shiv    10000
Ram     20000
Varun   30000
Syam    10000
```

Second sheet data, where formula should produce Salary from first one:

```
Name    Salary
Shi 
Ra  
Var 
Sya
```

Comment: You could progressively peel off the right-most character until you either ran out of characters or achieved a match. That would work for your sample data but there is no guarantee that it would work for other combinations. You could also investigate the [Fuzzy Lookup plugin](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011) to see if it could help.

Comment: Explain a little better; read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Answer (score 1):

In Sheet2!B2,

```
=VLOOKUP(A2&"*", Sheet1!A:B, 2, FALSE)
```

Fill down as necessary.